# Checked in Baggage transfer Dubai T2 to T3

Tags: luggage, dxb

Happy New Year!
I have a question regarding to my flight booked with fly dubai.
My flight from Erbil will land at T2 in Dubai and the.another flight will leave from terminal 3.

1- So for myself…i could use airport shuttle to move from T2 to T3?

2 - My checked baggage from 1st flight to 2nd flight will be automatically transferred by the fly dubai?

3 - or Do I need to exit from the airport through immigration and collect my checked baggage and check in again from T3?

4 - Any other important points I should be aware of?
Thank you.

Comment: What is your second flight?

Comment: Single ticket or two tickets? How much time between scheduled arrival in T2 to departure from T3? And as @MichaelHampton correctly asks: what's the destination of your second flight?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://www.flydubai.com/en/destinations/connections) from the flydubai site says that they will transfer the luggage for you via the “flydubai connect” service. It’s not completely obvious if this is standard or an option, though I don’t see any option for that in the booking process (the early part of it at least).

Of course this only works if you booked both flights on a single ticket.